# MySQL: Get DISTINCT values of repeated values and GROUP CONCAT of non-repeating values which are part of the same table

Tags: mysql

I have this table:
[image]
I want to get results something like this:
[image]

If you note,

1. I require the id of the first record which matches the condition. For example, ID 6 & 8 are the first record of SH001 - S2 & SH002 - S1, respectively.
2. Plus values in 'day' should be of proper sequence as shown & not like 'Fri,Mon,Thu'.

I tried some queries but it was not giving me the intended results. So can anyone help me in the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT MIN(id), show_id, show_name, season_id, GROUP_CONCAT(day)
FROM table
GROUP BY 2,3,4
```

Comment: Your solution is giving proper first four values but the sequence in group_concat is like 'Fri,Mon,Thu'. Can we do something about that?

Comment: @VarunKrish Add according ORDER BY clause into GROUP_CONCAT() function parameters.

Comment: Thanks, your solution plus the last suggestion worked perfectly for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, show_id, show_name, session_id, GROUP_CONCAT(day) FROM `table` GROUP BY show_id, show_name, session_id;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).